# Facebook comments integration

Tags: facebook, comments, facebook-fql

I am building a website that's displaying a couple Facebook photo albums, which I'm retrieving with FQL. I'd also like to add the comments plugin and all existing Facebook comments for each photo.

When I add this:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="[some facebook photo url]" data-num-posts="4" data-width="300"></div>
```

it isn't including all the comments already made about this photo on Facebook. Likewise, when I make a comment using my site's comment box, it doesn't show up in Facebook under that photo.

I'm guessing that the comments plugin doesn't have that functionality: To sync my site's comments with Facebook comments when using a Facebook url?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Comments don't come with the photos by default.  You have to get them with graph.facebook.com/PHOTO_ID/comments.